# Uploading files remotely just deletes the contents

Tags: windows-7, linux, sftp

I'm new to Linux, and for school I'm using a remote SSH shell via SSH Secure Shell Client 3.2.9 and SSH Secure File Transfer Client from Windows 7 to try to upload files.

We were going over the `chmod` command and I ended up setting my entire `$HOME` directory to `rwx` (777). Now, I cannot upload any file remotely (haven't tried at school): It uploads the file but deletes all content and displays 0 Bytes. Also, I can create a file...but if I concatenate or try to add anything to it, the command line acts like it processes it, but the file is still 0 Bytes.

I'm not sure what I've done exactly and how to fix it. I believe in trying to fix it I also went below my `$HOME` into the directory that holds all our schools csusers and set my directory there to like 755 or something.

I'll probably have to go talk to my professor, but I just wanted to try to fix it.

Comment: you will probably have to consult your schools technical staff. nothing about the chmod change you made should cause you to loose the ability to write files. quite the opposite in fact.

Comment: @FrankThomas agreed, +1. You might be wrong though, if the OP ran `chmod -R`, that would have changed the permissions of `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and related files which would probably screw with ssh connectivity. I seem to recall that ssh does not like those files to be world readable.

Comment: COuld you show us a specific example? Say you i) `ssh user@server`, then ii) echo "foo" > bar and then iii) `cat bar`. What happens?

Comment: When I do this, the exact thing I am describing happens.  The file is created, but there is not content.  After running the above commands, and running ls -l on the file.  It reads:                                     -rw------- 1 'name' group 0 Nov 14 10:36 bar                                    The -rw- is what bothers me, I think I have my mask set to 0022.  Also, even after setting different permissions, I still cannot add content to the file.